# Shelf Life of Homemade Panettone

Tags: baking, bread, cake, storage-lifetime

I'm thinking of making a few panettones for Christmas presents, this year. At what time would you recommend? This question is largely motivated by the potential for them to spoil or go stale; but also, if there's any maturation time, that would be good to know.

I'm guessing the water activity level is probably pretty low, so they won't spoil quickly and staleness would be more of a concern. I remember them being made commercially (in Italy) in October, but presumably they have access to better preservatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panettone is better consume in the first 2 to 3 days. Even if it comes from the supermarket.

After the second day I recommend you to heat the piece you are going to eat in the oven for 7-10 minutes. Raisins will become creamy again–and your kitchen will smell delicious–. I've lived in Italy and my Italian flatmate used this trick.

Giallo Zafferano says [you can freeze the dough after the last raising time](http://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Panettone.html)

[image]

Translation:

> Preservation
>
> Homemade panettone keeps its freshness less time than manufactured
>   panettone.
>
> You can preserve it for up to 2-3 days inside a plastic bag.
>
> It can be frozen after the last rising time. Defrost it inside the fridge and leave it there for at least 2 hours before kneading the dough again. Add the butter inside the cross and bake it.

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you... That's my Christmas Eve' sorted, then ;)